# Angular Routing - Load data into parent page before first route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I am using angular routing for a admin panel project. Following is my angular js code.

app.js

```
(function() {

var app = angular.module("app", [
    "ngRoute",
    "app.dashboard",
    "app.calendar",
    "app.event"
]);

var dashboard = angular.module("app.dashboard");

dashboard
    .config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/dashboard', {
            templateUrl: '/views/dashboard/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'DashBoardIndexController as ctrl'
        }).
        when('/dashboard/detail', {
            templateUrl: "/views/dashboard/detailgraph.html",
            controller: "DashBoardDetailController as ctrl"
        })
    });

......
......
//Controllers related to dashboard module

var calendar = angular.module("app.calendar");

calendar
    .config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/calendar', {
            templateUrl: '/views/calendar/calendar.html',
            controller: 'CalendarIndexController as ctrl'
        }).
        when('/calendar/markevent', {
            templateUrl: "/views/calendar/markevent.html",
            controller: "CalendarEventController as ctrl"
        })
    });

......
......
//Controllers related to calendar module

}());
```

For better code management, I am dividing various module of application and including them in main `app` module.

After login, the first route loaded will be of dashboard (/dashboard). But before route provider initialized and dashboard loaded, I need to fetch the user's rights level and accordingly create the side navigation menus in parent page. Below is my parent page:

home.html

```
    <body ng-app="app">
   <header>
      <nav id="mynav" class="bold z-depth-1" role="navigation">
         <div class="nav-wrapper container">
            <a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo text-darken-1">Logo</a>
            <div class="container">
               <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse top-nav full hide-on-large-only black-text"><i
                  class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i></a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </nav>
      <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav fixed center-align">
         <!-- This side menu items should be created based on user's rights --!>
      </ul>
   </header>
   <main class="grey lighten-4">
      <div id="main-container" class="container z-depth-1 ">
         <div ng-view=""></div>
      </div>
   </main>
```

As you can see, before ng-view is loaded with first route (/dashboard), I need to make server call to fetch the user's rights. I am relatively new to angular and I think we can do this by resolve promise. But here two modules are different (app and app.dashboard).

What could be the correct way to solve this problem?

Comment: Search for Angular UI router & you can use that to create nested states.

Comment: ui-router sounds good. I will replace it with angular routing. Thanks.